# How to connect oracle database in php

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm newbie in the connection of oracle database to php. Here's I want to happen. I want to call all data that I need in oracle database (which is my data warehouse) using php. But I don't know how. I read some articles and forums regarding in my problem. They say it need to have an OCI.dll and/or Oracle instant client, but I don't how to use it. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer portable and XAMPP latest version.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that copying OCI.dll from \$ORA_HOME\bin to \$ORA_HOME should sort this particular issue. There's [documentation for connecting to Oracle using PHP on the PHP website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php). If you have further problems, feel free to leave a comment and I'll gladly help further.

Comment: hi, i got an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\otrs\file.php on line 4

Answer (score 2):

resource oci_new_connect ( string $username , string $password [, string $connection_string [, string $character_set [, int $session_mode ]]] )

For more information you can refer this basic manual for connection http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-connect.php

Comment: hi, i got an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\otrs\file.php on line 4